# object compress is not a member of package org.apache.commons

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-commons

I've been trying to use the apache commons.
But, it fails and get the following errors.
I've no idea how to fix it. Maybe, need to add something into build.sbt?

```
$ sbt
> clean
> compile
[error] hw.scala:3: object compress is not a member of package org.apache.commons
[error] import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils
[error]                           ^
[error] hw.scala:24: not found: value IOUtils
[error]     val bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(imgFile))
[error]                 ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

hw.scala

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.{ Base64 => ApacheBase64 }
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils

...
```

build.sbt

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.10",
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your build.sbt:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-compress" % "1.14"
```

To find this by yourself in the future, search on https://mvnrepository.com/